# How to split a value to single decimal integer in C++

Tags: c++

I want to split 12345 into 1 2 3 4 5 in C++. How can I do that without using a modulus operator?.
Any useful STL to handle this?

Comment: Convert to string, then extract characters ?

Comment: why no modulo ?

Comment: the printing function does the modulo operation under the hood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, here is a solution that works via conversion to a string.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

const auto str = std::to_string(12345);
std::vector<int> result;

std::transform(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), std::back_inserter(result),
    [](auto c){ return c - 48; });
```

Note that the implementation of `std::to_string` probably uses the modulo operator, though.

Comment: I was thinking about a for_each, but this is much neater +1